# Can't create index in neo4j via $post in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, neo4j

I create simple web app, using neo4j REST API, JS and JQuery. I am able to create new node using `$post`:

```
$.post("http://localhost:7474/db/data/node",
{
    "name":data[i].name,
    "phone":data[i].phone
},  
function(jsonData) {
    newlyCreated = jsonData.self;
},
'json');
```

it works, new node is created and appears in db.

Unfortunately when I try to create index using `$post`, this syntax doesn't work:

```
$.post("http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node",{"name":"phone"},function(indexInfo) {
        console.log(indexInfo);
}, 'json');
```

When I try to use neo4j http console:

```
POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/ {"name": "phone"}
```

It works fine index is created.

Any suggestions why `$.post` doesn't work properly in this case?

Comment: If you can CURL it, this should be a javascript problem.

Comment: what error do you get back?

Comment: CURL doesn't have the allow origin restrictions as JavaScript so probably that is the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a no-no to send requests to Neo4j directly through JavaScript. Probably it doesn't work because of the Cross Origin ( No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'xxyy' is therefore not allowed access).

Usually Neo4j runs on port 7474, so if you're doing requests from port 80 (default http port) you're no allowed. Also, if you make request from the same port (like the browser does, you also need to add Authentication is that is enabled in your Neo4j configuration)

The security risk is that if you do direct request from a browser to a secure Neo4j, saving username and password in the browser will let anyone have direct access to your Neo4j instance.

So the best way is to create a proxy (with a Allow Origin configuration), that verify the request and if it's a valid one, authenticate and send it to the database, and return to the browser request the required data. :)